# REST API doesn't support SQL grouping. Is there a way to overcome this?

Tags: mysql, vtiger

A sample of my database. I have no control over how the database saves data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/155e3c/19

The problem is due to two factors:

1. The REST API (vTiger opensource CRM) does not support grouping.
2. For fields that store multiple picklist options, the database stores them in 1 field seperated by |##|.

What I want:
I want to be able to fetch queries based also on the presence of values in the multipicklist field, but because of the no grouping support I cannot do this without affecting the rest of my query.

So basically I am looking for a way to overcome this non-grouping situation and produce a query that will be equivalent to:

SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE car IN ('Toyota', 'Ferrari') AND (country LIKE '%Canada%' OR country LIKE '%Brazil%');

Is there a way to do this?

Addition:
If I just wanted to get all the options given by the user when searching a multipicklist field it would be ok because i would just use AND operator. but if I want only one of the options the non-grouped OR operator ruins my query.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to retrieve data that could not be obtained via the API queries support. I ended up creating my own webservices. You would need to create a module which you can develop locally and then deploy it to the production vtiger instance. You'd need a vtiger user with admin privileges on the production instance in order to install your module (you wouldn't need direct access to the database or files).

That way, you can create your own queries in mysql and wrap them up in functions like getContactsByCar(car_array).

Comment: Oh wow that sounds cool but I'm in the process of working it out differently.

So my solution (it isn't an elegant one but a creative one nonetheless) is to actually run an invertor on multipicklist options which would otherwise have the OR operator.

let's say cars: toyota, audi, ferrari, fiat.
my user wants any clients who was interested in audi or ferrari.

instead of running WHERE car='audi' OR car='ferrari'.

I invert the form multipicklist before sending it and reset it after sending it. then the handle is:
WHERE NOT car="toyota" AND NOT car='fiat'.

Comment: the queries you can do with the REST API are very basic and limited. Most likely, you will have to do what I did. If you haven't done a module for Vtiger there will be a learning curve, but you have few (no?) other options.

Comment: I ended up fetching the entire query and filtering out the JSON result manually before sending it out to the client-side. Not optimal by any chance but would be enough considering the low amount of users the product has.